# Sending a test/example alert from monit?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I've configured monit tests and alerts — but I want to make sure that everything in my alert stack (outgoing email servers, sms email gateways…) is functioning properly. Is there a handy way to fire off a dummy test alert?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I usually restart a trivial service (like ntp) that I'm monitoring in order to test the alerts.

I did find [this suggestion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2008-07/msg00022.html) in the mailing list archives...

It's a way to leverage the alert reminder functionality in Monit to ensure that the alert path is functioning properly. Basically, a periodic reminder. Tune the cycle to your liking and you'll be able to control the testing time.

```
  check file alerttest with path /.nonexistent
    alert address@hidden with reminder on 500 cycles
```

Comment: A [dead man's switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch), nice!

Answer (score 8):

Even easier is to just reload the config file and wait for the "Monit instance changed.."-email. Just run:

> monit reload

Comment: Doesn't work if the recipient is defined using `set alert manager@foo.bar not on { instance, action }`